# ASP.NET VirtualPathProvider.DirectoryExists() sometimes right, sometimes wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtualpathprovider

In my web app the following call returns true early during application startup, then returns false later for whatever reason:

```
HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.DirectoryExists("~/some/existing/directory")
```

The folder exists and at the same time the following code always correctly returns true:

```
System.IO.Directory.Exists(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/some/existing/directory"))
```

I have no idea what can affect VirtualPathProvider to change behaviour. The VirtualPathProvider is overridden on application start with a custom implementation but that doesn't override DirectoryExists() and the method actually called all times is `System.Web.Hosting.MapPathBasedVirtualPathProvider`.

I checked with Process Monitor and the file system operation that happens is the same for the right and the wrong result.

Anybody with an idea what can break `DirectoryExists()` (and BTW the same happens for `FileExists()`)?

Comment: Interesting, is it happened in one single http Request or intermittently  in more than one single http Request?

Comment: This is within the same request on app start; then on subsequent requests only the broken version happens. It has to be told though that the startup of this app (Orchard: http://orchardproject.net/) is quite lengthy and complicated; thus I suspect there is something messing up VPP but I'd need a hint what to look for as I can't find any traces.